# How can I debug problems related to (lack of) postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have created a custom wizard control that dynamically loads usercontrols as you progress though it. The wizard is behaving as expected in all environments (PC/MAC) and browsers I have tested however a client is reporting that she is unable to complete the wizard. What I know about the issue:

- It always fails on the same wizard step for this user (not the first step)
- When the user clicks on the 'next' button in the step, the controller reports that the request was not a postback request (ie. IsPostBack() == false) and displays the first page of the wizard
- The client is using a Mac and is accessing the site using the latest version of Safari
- If the client switches to Firefox, or even just switches the user agent in Safari to something other than Safari the problem goes away.

So the problem is that when the client reaches a certain step in the wizard and clicks 'next', instead of re-loading that step to initiate the save event, the controller is merely displaying the first step of the wizard.

The step that fails contains many different form controls including textboxes, dropdowns, checkboxes and a fileupload control. We thought that it might have something to do with invalid characters getting pasted in from Word or something similar but that seems strange seeing as the problem only appears to be happening in Safari.

No exceptions are thrown and the windows event log is not displaying any related errors/warnings.

What I am looking for is ways to diagnose this error. At the moment I've been unable to reproduce the behavior that the client is experiencing but after going on site and seeing it for myself I can verify that it is definitely a valid issue.

**Update 26/10/2010:**

We installed a [proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) on the clients NIC in order to retrieve the requests and responses. Problem is that when running the proxy the client appears to not have to problem any more. Does this behavior make sense to anyone?

**Update 27/10/2010:**

After investigating the traffic on the clients machine we noticed that the response headers were including some entries related to a client side proxy and we confirmed that they are in fact running the squid proxy in their office. To rule out that it had anything to do with the problem we got them to turn if off and then try the wizard again. This time no problems were encountered! So the proxy seems to be interfering with the requests causing .NET to somehow record the POST request as a non-postback. The following lines were found in the response header of a failed request. Can anyone comment on how squid could cause the behavior we are experiencing and what we can do about it?

> Via:1.0 squid-12 (squid/3.1.0.13), 1.0 ClientSiteProxy:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE4)
>
> X-Cache:MISS from squid-12, MISS from ClientSiteProxy
>
> X-Cache-Lookup:MISS from ClientSiteProxy:3128

Comment: By any chance are you creating and appending cookies when you press next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not solved as such but we ended up just adding an exception to the clients squid proxy to bypass our website. The problem seems proxy/IIS/Safari related but we haven't been able to track the problem down any further and the client is happy with this solution as long as the problem doesn't resurface somewhere else. I'll re-post if more information surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

If I have to troubleshoot this, I would first take a fiddler trace (www.fiddlertool.com) on the client and see what the requests are up to. I am not sure if Fiddler works on Mac, but any HTTP Watch, Network Monitor tool should be good. The reason that I am not doubting the code is that it works very well on all the other browsers, so the code shouldn't be bad.

May be there is something in the code [like adding cookies, etc] that is messing with the specific Client's browser.

HTH,
Rahul

Comment: We do use a couple of session variables but nothing specific to that step.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac There's a [HTTPScoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/) which lets you to debug http post data's....it is similar to fiddler